# Natural graph class with five excluded subgraphs?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-classes

I'm interested in hereditary graph classes characterized by a small number of excluded subgraphs. There are some well-known graph classes that are characterized by three or four obstructions -- examples are threshold graphs, chain grapns and trivially perfect graphs. My question is: are there natural graph classes characterized by five obstructions? (No relation to the eponymous movie). It may be possible to obtain some by considering the P4-structure of the graph.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder how many of the "super\d" accounts belong to the same person :P.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly five or just more than four? If the latter, then the class of line graphs is an answer: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph

Comment: Just have a look [here](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes.cgi); you can then decide for yourself what exactly you consider natural out of them, if any :-)

Comment: To R B: yes, they belong to the same person, I'm just alternating between "circle-shaped digits" like 0/3/5/9.

Comment: To Juho: I think the website contain one interesting such class, but there may exist several other ones "in the limbo".

Comment: @Super3 it is easier to participate on the site if you register an account. We can then merge your 4 other accounts with it.

Comment: Is there a motivation for exactly 5 forbidden subgraphs?

Answer (score 3):

The "**split-substitute**" graphs are the graphs starting with a split graph and substituting any split graph into any node.
The forbidden induced subgraphs can be obtains from the forbidden induced subgraphs of split graphs (c4, C5, co-C4), but replacing the non-prime ones (c4 and co-c4) with their minimal prime extensions... (here primality is with respect with modular decomposition.)

So the 5 forbidden induced subgraphs are the C5, P5, co-P5, H6 and co-H6. This forms a self-complementary class which strictly contains the class of cographs.

See: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~hayward/papers/p4comp.online.pdf

---

The **maxibrittle** graphs are the perfectly orderable graphs for which a vertex sequence defined only by the degrees will produce a perfect order (more specifically, the degree sequence defines a brittle ordering). These graphs have exactly 5 minimal forbidden induced subgraphs.

Answer (score 2):

Graphs where every connected component is a split graph are (C4, C5, P5, necktie, bowtie)-free (see [A graph modification approach for finding core–periphery structures in protein interaction networks](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186%2Fs13015-015-0043-7)).

Answer (score 0):

After browsing the [ISGCI](http://www.graphclasses.org/) site I came across the following class: [opposition graphs](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_89.html).
They seem a possible candidate for your question, but is their obstruction set known?

Comment: I don't see how they can be a candidate... a complete minimal forbidden induced subgraph characterization for them is currently unknown but I'm pretty sure it is known to be infinite.

Comment: Indeed, V B L has given a list of an infinite family of co-bipartite graphs which are minimal non-opposition, as well as an infinite family of trees which are minimal non-opposition graphs in this paper: http://www.informatik.uni-rostock.de/~le/Research/coop.pdf

Comment: By the way, do you know a self-contained proof that opposition graphs are perfect? I.e. one that doesn't use Chudnovsky et al. proof of the 'KGT' or the Olariu proof from refs '19-04' in the paper.